# Model turns grey/black/invisible in certain angles, when I switch my render engine to eevee?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Im new to blender, as this is my first animation. Im not sure what could be the problem, as I have tried many different solutions on the internet, but still can not find one that solves my exact issue. I will add some screenshots of how it looks in blender when in eevee and cycles. I would really appreciate a answer in some simple terminology.[image] [image]